# pyspark: geting a timeout on rdd.toLocalIterator()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

I am getting a time-out when trying to iterate over rdd. created from a dataFrame using .toLocalIterator()

The dataset is big

Pyspark 2.0 and python 2.7

```
----> 2     for dataRow in dataFrame.select(['uid', fieldName]).rdd.toLocalIterator():
      3         if isinstance(dataRow[fieldName], DenseVector):
...

/srv/software/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _load_from_socket(port, serializer)
--> 142         for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):

/srv/software/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py in load_stream(self, stream)
--> 139                 yield self._read_with_length(stream)

/srv/software/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py in _read_with_length(self, stream)
--> 156         length = read_int(stream)

/srv/software/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py in read_int(stream)
--> 543     length = stream.read(4)

/home/pcardoso/.conda/envs/libV2/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in read(self, size)
--> 384                     data = self._sock.recv(left)

timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Well, as you said: it is big. If you work in yarn-client, it is normal. You can try with yarn-cluster and play with spark parameter. See configuration/tuning page

Comment: I'm getting the same error using `mesos` and spark2. Which parameter would I play with. There are many of them!